# Issue with labeled arguments in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

This line of OCaml:

```
let c ~f = f() in let () = c (fun () -> ()) in ()
```

leads to the following error on the `c (fun () -> ())` expression:

```
File "tst.ml", line 1, characters 27-43:
Error: This expression has type f:(unit -> (unit -> unit) -> 'a) -> 'a
       but an expression was expected of type unit
```

Without the `~`, there is no error. There is also no error if I explicitly label the argument with `c ~f:(fun -> ())`.

How is the labeling messing things up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what is happening, I believe. You're trying to use the following special case for functions with labeled parameters:

> As a special case, if the function has a known arity, all the arguments are unlabeled, and their number matches the number of non-optional parameters, then labels are ignored and non-optional parameters are matched in their definition order. Optional arguments are defaulted.

([Section 7.7.1 of the OCaml manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html).)

But in your definition, `c` doesn't have a known arity. This is because `f` can return a function, and hence `c` can return a function.

Since the special case doesn't apply, the compiler has to assume that the labeled argument `~f:` hasn't appeared yet, and that it *does* return a function. Hence you get the typing you see in your example.

If you redefine `c` so that it has a known arity (so that it can't return a function), things work as you expect.

```
# let c ~f = [ f () ];;
val c : f:(unit -> 'a) -> 'a list = <fun>
# c (fun () -> ());;
- : unit list = [()]
```